# auto-incrementation version in gitlab-ci

Tags: maven, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I need to do auto-incrementation version on my project. The version looks like 0.0.1. At the moment I have done in .gitlab-ci.yml a version of && git add. && git push. I use a technical user for this because, according to the information, the access token to the project's repository is read-only. Is there any better way to do this? Ideally, this could be achieved without a technical user.

this is fragment of my gitlab-ci stage :

```
before_script:
    - apt-get update -y && apt-get install git 
    - git config --global user.email $USER_MAIL
    - git config --global user.name $USER_NAME
  script:
    - ./mvnw build-helper:parse-version versions:set -DnewVersion=\${parsedVersion.majorVersion}.\${parsedVersion.minorVersion}.\${parsedVersion.nextIncrementalVersion} versions:commit
    - ./mvnw clean install -Pdev
    - git add .
    - git commit -m "auto increment"
    - git push "https://$USER_NAME:$USER_PASS@${CI_REPOSITORY_URL#*@}" "HEAD:XXXX" -o ci.skip
```

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example of your .gitlab-ci.yml